pnpm patch successfully patches the project, but the patch does not take effect when the project is running?
I found a problem with el-form, so I decided to patch element-ui in my project.

vite@3.0.2, vue@2.7.7, pnpm, element-ui@^2.15.14

I ran pnpm patch element-ui@^2.15.14

The root directory patches file is also generated

package.json has also changed

code has also changed in node_modules/element-ui

After I run the code (pnpm dev), the problem still exists. After debugging, I found that the source code has not been changed.

I have tried clearing the cache (pnpm prune), or deleting the package (node_modules) and reinstalling it, or clearing the cache (deleting node_modules/.vite and running pnpm dev --force), but the problem still exists.

I changed the wrong file (node_modules/element-ui/packages/form/src/label-wrap.vue) before. The problem was that the file form-item.js threw it, and the entry file of element-ui was element-ui.common.js. So I changed the getLabelWidth method of the node_modules/element-ui/lib/form-item.js file
getLabelWidth: function getLabelWidth() {
  if (this.$el && this.$el.firstElementChild) {
  var computedWidth = window.getComputedStyle(this.$el.firstElementChild).width;
  return computedWidth == 'auto' ? 'auto' : Math.ceil(parseFloat(computedWidth));
 } else {
   return 0;
 }
},

Finally it worked,
